# Two dimensional array of string in struct-C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to make a two dimensional array in a struct using pointer since I am new to c and get quite confuse in the topic of pointer. Help please!

```
struct course
{
    char *coursecode;
    char *coursesession[5];
};

int main()
{

    int n = 0;
    int numSession = 0;
    struct course *main = malloc(sizeof(struct course));



    printf("Enter the course code and the session in this order:");
    scanf("%s", main->coursecode);
    printf("Enter the number of session required:");
    scanf("%d", &numSession);
    for (int i = 0; i < numSession; ++i)
        {
            printf("Enter the session code (M1...):");
            scanf("%s", main->coursesession[i]);
        }
    ++n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `coursecode` to be a pointer to `char`, but you need to allocate space for it, which you can do with `malloc`.

And you've declared `coursesession` to be an array of 5 pointers to `char`.  You need to allocate space for all 5 pointers, again with `malloc`.

Alternatively, you could declare both of them as arrays, e.g.

```
struct course
{
    char coursecode[100];
    char coursesession[5][100];
};
```

This declares `coursecode` to be an array of 100 `char`, and `coursesession` to be an array of 5 arrays of 100 `char`.  Obviously you could adjust the `100` to whatever you need, but the storage size would be fixed regardless.

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: But how can i get the input from the user in that case?

Comment: @madness Which case are you asking about, the pointer case or the fixed-size array case?

Comment: the fixed-sized case please

Comment: @madness Ok, well in the fixed-size case, it's just like any other array.  You would basically have to place a maximum limit on the string sizes up front.  The strings could of course be smaller, but they could never be larger, and of course you would be using the full amount of storage regardless of the string sizes.  Don't forget to include space for the terminating null character.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct course
{
   char *coursecode;
   char *coursesession[5];
};

int main()
{

    int n,i = 0;
    int numSession = 0;
    struct course main;

    main.coursecode = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter the course code and the session in this order:");
    scanf("%s", main.coursecode);
    printf("Enter the number of session required:");
    scanf("%d", &numSession);
    for (i = 0; i < numSession; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the session code (M1...):"); 
        main.coursesession[i] = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", main.coursesession[i]);
    }
    ++n;
    free(main.coursecode);
    for (i = 0; i < numSession; ++i){
        free(main.coursesession[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` as it is not required in C. And if you are going to use a fixed size buffer as in `malloc(100*sizeof(char))`, please don't use `scanf` which could cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: @MFisherKDX -- it is fine to use `scanf()` with a "fixed size buffer", but a maximum field width should be specified in the format string to avoid buffer overflow, e.g. `scanf("%99s", main.coursesession[i]);`.